# How can I autoloading Bower dependencies like with Composer?

Tags: javascript, symfony, composer-php, bower, autoload

With Composer I can simply autoload vendors, can I autoloading bower components in my HTML page like Symfony framework autoload with Composer? I need to autoload next dependencies from `bower.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
    "ckeditor": "~4.4.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`SpBowerBundle`](https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle), it could solve your problem.

It allows you to define a `bower.json` in any bundle, and use dependencies defined there in your templates almost in the same way as you'd do with regular assets. And note it's still in development, so things could change over time.